# Saving values in to array and displaying it based on the number

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angularjs

I have the following code written in angular JS

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="person_info">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Person info</title>
<script src="../angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="controller_class2.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
.forms{width:200px;height:300px;padding:75px;float:left;background:#CCC;}
.deatils{width:200px;height:auto;padding:100px;float:left;background:#CCC;margin-    left:10px;}
.fields {background:#999999;float: left;height:120px;padding: 20px;width:260px;}
</style>
</head>
<body ng-controller="info">
<div class="forms"> Name:</br>
  <input type="text" value="name" ng-model="person.name">
  </br>
  </br>
  First Name :</br>
  <input type="text" value="fname" ng-model="person.firstname">
  </br>
  </br>
  Phone Number :</br>
  <input type="number"  value="number" ng-model="person.number">
  </br>
  </br>
  Email :</br>
  <input type="email" value="email" ng-model="person.email">
  </br>
  </br>
  Address :</br>
  <input type="text" value="address" ng-model="person.address">
  </br>
  </br>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" ng-click="test()">
</div>

<div class="deatils">
<p>Name : {{person.name}}</p>
<p>First Name : {{person.firstname}}</p>
<p>Phone Number: {{person.number}}</p>
<p>Email : {{person.email}}</p>
<p>Address :{{person.address}}</p></br></br>
 <p>Details in json format : </br>{{ person | json }}
</div>

<div class="fields">
Submit the persons serial number to display his details
   </br>
  </br>
<input type="number" >
  </br>
  </br>
<input type="submit" value="submit number">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller code

```
var person_info = angular.module('person_info', []);

person_info.controller('info', function($scope) {
  $scope.test = function () {
    console.log($scope.person);
  }
});
```

When the user fills the form and click on submit button i want the details to be saved into a array and clear all the field so that the next users details can be filled. each user details will be stored in the array.

i have also created a text field where user can enter the serial number of the user whose detail have to be displayed. for example when i enter the value 3 and submit this. the 3rd person's details in the array have to be displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can define a function like your `test()` function in your controller to save current model into an array and clear it, here is **example function**,

```
  $scope.savePerson = function () {
    $scope.personList.push($scope.person);
    //clear person model/form
    $scope.person = {};
  };
```

and here is **html form**,

```
<div class="forms">
    Name: <input type="text" value="name" ng-model="person.name">
    First Name : <input type="text" value="fname" ng-model="person.firstname">
    Phone Number : <input type="number" value="number" ng-model="person.number">
    Email : <input type="email" value="email" ng-model="person.email">
    Address : <input type="text" value="address" ng-model="person.address">
    <input type="submit" ng-click="savePerson()">
  </div>
```

and define another function to **retrieve data** from your `personList[]` array like this,

```
  $scope.getPerson = function (index) {
    //selected person details
    $scope.personDetail = $scope.personList[index];
  };
```

of course you shoudl make few changes in your html as well, here is full [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/9cZXCEgUUzbiAhabhCO7) of my solution...

Comment: How can i include savePerson() function on ng-click? i already have test function called on ng-click. will i add the codes in savePerson() in test() itself?

Comment: @Shareer I replaced test function with savePerson in html, look at my plunker example and I ll update my soulution with html code...

Comment: Thanks for the code. but itseems that there is something wrong with what i did. the values entered are not clearing when submitted for the next persons value to be entered.

Comment: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined . This is the error what i am getting in console

Comment: @Shareer look at my controller function, you should define your array, you cannot use push() method on undefined object try to define array in your controller like this $scope.personList = [];... did you look at plunker cause there is full solution there I only copy necessary part of the solution...

Comment: Yes wick. you have been very helpful. now it seems to work fine. but the class 'fields' doesn't seen to work properly. it doesn't display the details of the user when i enter their index number.

Comment: @Shareer yes, because I bind it to another model, if you bind second form to personDetail model instead person it will show you what you want...

Comment: I tried and it seems to be some error. it will be great if you can share the code wick

Comment: @Shareer man that's why I created a plunker for you just go to link and you will see all my doing just to this link http://plnkr.co/edit/9cZXCEgUUzbiAhabhCO7?p=preview

Comment: @Shareer accept it as answer if it helps you to solve problem man :D

Answer (score 0):

you can try extracting the value using `.serialize()` like this

```
var count=0;  
var formArr={}; 
$('.forms input[type=submit]').on('click',function () {
    formArr[count++]=$( "form" ).serialize();  //this would serialize the form data
    // clear the form data for next client details entry
    $(':input','#myform')
      .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
      .val('')
      .removeAttr('checked')
      .removeAttr('selected');
}); 

$('.fields input[type=submit]').on('click',function () {
    var serNo=$(this).find ('input[type=text]').val();
    var formData= formArr[serNo];
    formData=formData.split("&");
    for(i=0;i<formData.length;i++)
    {
         $('input[name='+ formData[i]+']').val(formData[++i]);   
    }
});
```

*Note: this is untested code, it may require few code tunings*

Happy Coding :)